# SCDF Deployment Failure : CF-NotAuthorized(10003)

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Getting the following error when deploying SCDF stream app on PCF :

o.s.c.d.s.c.AbstractCloudFoundryDeployer : Failed to deploy ....
 2019-07-31T09:54:11.38-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.cloudfoundry.client.v2.ClientV2Exception: CF-NotAuthorized(10003): You are not authorized to perform the requested action

I'm using an ldap service account.
Is the service account missing permissions ?

Comment: There's not much information here to decipher what could have gone wrong. Clearly, though, the Cloud Controller is choking and the user that you're impersonating, it doesn't have "space-developer" access.

Comment: You may want to edit the post with versions in use, background on how you're provisioning SCDF on PCF, how were SCDF and LDAP configurations set up along with the sample `manifest.yml` files of SCDF and Skipper (of course, redact any sensitive credentials from it).